# Become master in two different infosec fields

Tags: malware, penetration-test, reverse-engineering, career

I need career advice.
I'm deeply,insanely interested in two fields of cyber security:

1. Malware Analysis
2. Web/System/Network Penetration Testing

I have lots of learning resources about pentesting and malware analysis, books,video courses,papers and etc. But as I go further I realize how much I don't know and how much I need to learn.For example, I was learning about web application penetration testing but some problem rose because I didn't know a lot about web application developing.The same goes to Malware Analysis(RE).I was reading Practical Malware Analysis book and problem rose because I didn't know enough assembly and it become necessary to learn assembly first.

I remember this phrase: "**Person chasing two rabbits catches neither**".
What is your opinion and if it is possible to be expert in multiple fields,assuming I'm not genius guy :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Higgs - before posting, please read our [about] and [ask] pages which will help you understand our site scope. Career advice is off topic here.

Comment: @RoryAlsop yes, I know It is question that will have opinion based answers. Where is appropriate place to ask this question?
I just thought it would be good to ask to people who have experience.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not suitable for opinion based answers at all.